# how to refresh data in JTabbedPane?

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel, jtabbedpane

sir/mem , how to update the images content in the jLabel ,and how to refresh the this JTabbedpane , that contain Jlabel?

Comment: To change image use setIcon method of JLabel and then call repaint/revalidate of container which contains Jlabel to refresh the tab.

Comment: @HarryJoy the question is a bit unclear, but anyway: manual repaint/revalidate shouldn't be necessary after setting an icon

Comment: @kleopatra right there could be discusion only if required ImageIcon#getImage().flush() or not, but in other hand (revalidate for some JComponents calling for invalidate) could be replaced with revalidate & repaint :-), sorry I can't find out nice describtion by Rob about ImageIcon#getImage().flush()

Comment: thanks to all of u for help to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify Swing components in the *Event Dispatch Thread*, otherwise such updates may not be visible even though they occurred.

Comment: what r u saying , i cant get exact meaning of that, and how to make this methodin my program?

Comment: @Jay, Please read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)